# What are some objective truths in ethics?

Tags: ethics

Someone told me that the idea that there's no objective truth in ethics is highly debatable. I am wondering what are some purported objective truths identified or claimed by various philosophers throughout the years. I am thinking there might be one or two extremely simple assertions that could be objectively true, but I can't really think of any of them.

Comment: Objectivity is a myth. 'What is an objective property?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82527/what-is-an-objective-property/82529#82529 I give my definition of ethics here: 'Ethics: a simple definition using simple words' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/83088/ethics-a-simple-definition-using-simple-words/83104#83104 Game theory helps us understand how we get emergent cultural dynamic, rather than 'final truths'

Comment: See [Moral Realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism/). Religious believers assert that God's commands (or rather value claims behind them) are objective moral truths. Kant's categorical imperative for rational agents in various formulations (e.g. the humanity formula "*never treat others merely as a means to an end, but always as ends in themselves*") is a secular version of it.

Comment: Go back to who ever told you that there is "no objective truth in ethics" and ask this: "is your statement about there is no objective truth a SUBJECTIVE CLAIM itself?" It seems to me that if the claim about the lack of objective truth is always true then that makes the claim OBJECTIVE itself. 2ndly ethics is not identical to moral in Philosophy. Too many people think they are the same which is incorrect. Morals express universal rules for all people on the planet period. Ethics has  individual components: medical ethics, military ethics, business ethics, etc. These aren't for everyone.

Comment: Hmm, should I ask the difference between them in another question?

Comment: @CriglCragl:  "Objectivity is a myth" would require objectivity to be valid (or invalid).  Is it?

Comment: @TheDoctor: The old argument by lack of imagination, huh. Circular reasoning in fact, with your premises in your conclusion: all statements of truth must be objective, therefore objectivity exists. In science we have to deal with tentative truth, the picture so far, from evidence we have. It doesn't have to have ever grasped 'the objective truth', to be our best model so far. Newton's gravity was wrong, but effective in many circumstances. Without a 'god's eye view' there is no  one to decide eg time ordering.  We have instead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net

Comment: @Logikal: The morality of abortion depends on how you judge what makes personhood, weigh capacities & potential, & other complex matters. Can there be only one correct answer on what laws or rules there should be? How is it calculated if so?

Comment: @CriglCragl what I as saying is that whatever laws or rules that you come up with MUST apply universally everywhere on Earth or you do not get to call it part of Morality as a subject. That would be Ethics.  More likely you are entering descriptive ethics or what some people call application ethics.  These are not constants in the field of knowledge.  Moral knowledge must be universal by definition or we might as well get rid of the term Moral because it would make no sense. The new term MORAL is useless if it is already synonymous to what we already had before we invented the new term.

Comment: @Logikal: You seem to have arrived at your own special definition. From Etymonline: "Moral: from Latin moralis 'proper behavior of a person in society' literally 'pertaining to manners' coined by Cicero, to translate Greek ethikos. From Latin mos (genitive moris) 'one's disposition' " A moral, is typically a lesson or guidance drawn from a story or account. Do you think there must only be one lesson from each story?

Comment: @CriglCragl, you have two entire words confused: MORAL & MORLE of a story.  One is a field of Philosophy while the other is NOT intended to be used as a universal system of knowledge. The morale of a story doesn't prescribe how all people should act or not act. At best it may describe how some time behavior will pay off with an advantage.  MORAL under Philosophy falls under NORMATIVE ETHICS which may confuse people into thinking ethics & MORAL are interchangeable. They are not. Ethics has multiple fields inside of it. Philosophy only considers  two: normative ethics & meta ethics. You can look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controversial issue isn't whether there are some objective truths in ethics, but whether statements about ethics are the kinds of statements that can be objectively true at all. This is an old and well-travelled problem in ethics. A moral realist would say that moral truths are just what they seem to be. If I promise to pay you $20 then I have an obligation to pay you $20, and if I fail to do so, I have done something objectively wrong.

Notice that I used ethics-related terms to describe ethics: "obligation" and "wrong". How do I define what ethical behavior is without using ethics-related words? Most moral realists would say that you can't. The class of ethical "things" like obligations and wrongness is a different category of thing from anything else. They aren't physical objects, they aren't thoughts, and they aren't abstract objects, nor can they be reduced to any of these things. Consequently, you can only describe ethical terms in ethical terms, much like you can only describe physical terms in physical terms and abstract terms in abstract terms. For example, if you are trying to describe where Dallas is, you have to refer to other physical things such as Texas, or at least the earth.

There are two big problems with moral realism. First is the status of these moral objects. What kinds of things are they and how do we know about them? The other, related problem is that there is no agreement on what is moral and what is not. If people can't agree on an object, one obvious implication is that the object is not real. However, every alternative to moral realism has other implications that are also undesireable.

The other approaches to ethics all try to reduce statements about ethical "things" to statements about some other sort of things. Epicureanists believe that moral good is equivalent to pleasure. In other words, they reduce "X is good" to something like "X gives me pleasure" or, if they want to try to construct something similar to traditional morality, they might reduce it to "X is good because it provides the most pleasure for the most people". The problem with this approach is that it has unfortunate moral consequences; for example, it is good to torture a man to death if watching the torture is entertaining for enough people that their pleasure outweighs his pain.

Moral relativists reduce ethics to something like laws or conventions. In other words, what is morally good for you to do is based on your upbringing or the society in which you live. This theory also has unfortunate moral consequences. According to theories like this, the Aztec priests who ripped children away from their weeping parents and sacrificed them to the gods were doing something morally good.

Moral pragmatism reduces morality to effectiveness or practicality. In one version of this, moral codes are designed to optimize the safety and interactions of everyone in society. For example, trade can only work if people keep their word, so you have an obligation to keep your word. The problem with this version is that it doesn't make it immoral to cheat, so long as you don't get caught, so moral obligations only matter when other people are watching.

The evolutionary approach to morality is the idea that morals are just how we  have evolved to interact with each other, that there is some evolutionary advantage to behaving morally. The problem with this approach is that it makes genocide moral.

The only one of these theories that can allow for objective obligations is the realist theory because all of the others reduce "X is wrong" to something else:

**Epicurianism**: X is not the best way to experience pleasure.

**Relativism**: X is unconventional.

**Pragmatism**: If everyone did X, society would not work as well.

**Evolution**: X goes against evolutionary programming.

None of these is really the same as saying that you should not do X just because it is wrong. They all give some other reason to not do X. So when someone says that a moral judgment is objective and real, they are appealing to moral realism.

There are various other approaches and an enormous literature on the topic. If you are interested, I suggest you start with the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, which is a tremendous online resource.

Answer (score 0):

Ill-formed question: *ethics does not define any truth*.

To start, ethics is a system of rules, that is, a coherent set of statements that rule behavior. For example, *do not kill*, *help the suffering*, etc. System means a set of interrelated parts; ethics is a system because it defines rules at multiple levels: ideals, behavior, social interaction, interaction with God, etc.

Notice that following the definition, ethics is a *COHERENT* set of rules, this implies the use of logic, but not to relate rules with the truth (that is, it is not with the intention to say "this rule is true"); it is only to follow a coherent behavior. For example, if the first rule would be "kill", then, both rules would be contradictory, because you would waste your time trying to kill people and at the same time, trying to make them survive.

So, how do we know, for example, if "ethics is good"?, which is a question that CAN be associated with an ideally "objective" truth (objectivity is normally considered a shared agreement)?

Ethics per se does not target "good", or "altruism", or "survival". What connects ethics with truth are *ethical theories*: *utilitarianism, kantianism, aristotelianism*, etc. For example, *utilitarianism* states that the choice that provides good to most people is the right one. So, if you should decide between "kill" and "don't kill", you evidently will choose the second.

Regarding the meaning of good, that is another topic, and that's not related only with ethics, but to any system of rules. The theory that I consider most valid is the one that states that *good is related to the survival of the group* (read once in some phil. paper), that is, that *systems of rules target survival*.

So, if a gang of drug traffickers are confronted to the decision of killing someone if the group risks its existence, they will do so. Evidently, there's another system of rules that take more people into account: state law & justice. So, if justice notices that the lives of society members are in danger due to the group of traffickers, traffickers need to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

One such truth, if the question is to be considered valid:  reason and logic are essential.

In other words, if you want objectivity, you'll need these tools.  It's tautological.  You might say that ethics must rest on them, otherwise the notion of ethics (and the question) are non-sensical.

Comment: This post desperately needs details!

Comment: Needs references to support.

Comment: TheDoctor. I note your answer but it really does need expansion and argument. Unless you supply these, the answer will have to be deleted. It stands, pending revision.

Comment: While I agree with this, it is **not** objective in an absolute sense. Some people may insist that ethics given by (their) God is not subject to logical reasoning since (their) God is self-contradictory.